# Azure ML - how to import video into Python notebooks?

Tags: python, azure, opencv

I am trying to use OpenCV for some work on video analysis.
I wanted to import the video file into an Azure ML experiment.
When I try to load it from local , I did not find a supporting format ( there is a zip option though , not sure if that would help).If there any way I can work with a video ( without use of MS provided API ) in a Python notebook on a Azure ML work space ?

[Azure Doc link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/studio/import-data)

Plain text (.txt)
Comma-separated values (CSV) with a header (.csv) or without (.nh.csv)
Tab-separated values (TSV) with a header (.tsv) or without (.nh.tsv)
Excel file
Azure table
Hive table
SQL database table
OData values
SVMLight data (.svmlight) (see the SVMLight definition for format information)
Attribute Relation File Format (ARFF) data (.arff) (see the ARFF definition for format information)
Zip file (.zip)
R object or workspace file (.RData)

Answer (score 0):

First off, I would recommend trying to re-import using the zip option to see if that works.
Found this [useful documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/studio-module-reference/opencv-library-modules) on existing modules in Azure Machine Learning Studio that support use of the Open Source Computer Vision (OpenCV) Library. Hope this helps as you build your ML project. The modules in Studio provide a way to easily incorporate the OpenCV Library into your machine learning experiments. 
The OpenCV Library category includes these modules: 
• [Import Images](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/studio-module-reference/import-images): Loads images from Azure blob storage into a dataset.
• [Pretrained Cascade Image Classification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/studio-module-reference/pretrained-cascade-image-classification): Creates a pretrained image classification model for frontal faces using the OpenCV Library.
For additional image recognition features, see the image APIs published as part of [Microsoft Cognitive Services](https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services):